# Which verb is used to tell: check and pass it

Tags: meaning, word-choice, verbs

I'm looking for a *verb* that when I'm saying: ***XXX it***, then I would mean: ***Check it and if it was valid, pass it*** What should be the ***XXX***? Or any verb that have a similar meaning as the mentioned sentence.

EDIT: I removed the ***to me*** from the sentence.

Comment: 'Endorse', 'approve' and 'sanction' are used in a formal register, but 'OK' as a verb is surely more common.

Comment: i think the OP means "pass it to me... [checking first]".  I don't think there's a word for that.

Comment: Do you have a clearer example in your mind where you'd like to use this @ccsadegh?

Comment: You could use "validate", but as suggested by @JoeBlow, the fact that the passing on is implied may not be obvious for people unfamiliar with your use of the word. Any of the above suggestions should work fine within a group of people in a company or organisation.

Comment: @Neeku, I need a verb to name a function in a programming language.

Comment: @ccsadegh: "[*filter*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(higher-order_function))"

Comment: Hmm @ccsadegh, you could use something like "validateAndPass" if that's a function name. I know it's long, but a language like Objective-C not only doesn't contradict it, but also agrees with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a programmer by trade, I believe I can provide some insight here.  A Function already passes a value in a Return Statement.  As such, you don't need the "and pass" implied in the function name.  Instead you need a name, as in a noun.  Consider the following:

```
Private Function ValidateAge(AgeToCheck As Integer) As Boolean

Select Case AgeToCheck 
Case >= 21
    MsgBox("This Person can Drink or Smoke in the US")
    Return True
Case  > 18 And <=21
    MsgBox("This Person can vote in the US")
    Return True
Case < 16
    MsgBox("This Person is legally unable to vote, smoke, or drink.")
    Return False
Else
    Return False
End Case

End Function
```

If I only called this function Validate or Check, as in `Function Validate` or `Function Check` most programers would have to read code to see what the Function was doing, because the Function is only named with a verb.  As common practice, most seasoned programmers name functions with a verb plus a noun.  Common examples I've seen:

1. Function Tally.  I renamed it Function SumColumn Sum is a verb, Column is a noun.
2. Function Add.  I renamed it to Function AddItemToArray.  Add Is the Verb, Item is a noun. Array is a Return object
3. Function Iterate. I renamed it Function IterateStringToWord.  In this instance, same as #2 there are three helpers.  Iterate is the verb, String is a noun, an Word, also a noun, implies the Return object.

Comment: What's With the Random Title Case?

Comment: Programming Habit, I'll edit it

Comment: Ah, I figured you were *ein Deutschlander*.

Comment: What would be the function name if the `ValidateAge` function returns an integer (the age itself) or throws an exception if it is invalid?

Comment: Has been Edited  The Code is "Title Cased" to easily separate words, as spaces aren't allowed.

Comment: @ccsadegh The Function would Still be ValidateAge.  Inspection would yield the return type.  `As Integer` vs `As Boolean`  The Noun implies what argument the Function accepts.  Notice that AgeToCheck is an Integer

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is *validate*. It means either or both (a) to check whether something is valid and (b) to make or declare something to be valid.